# How can I use etckeeper via sudo with different users and have the correct user in the commit message?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, git, sudo, etckeeper

I'm working on a server with several admin users. Each of them can use `sudo` to make configuration changes. We're keepeing our `/etc` directory version-controlled using *etckeeper*.

However, when I or another admin calls `sudo etckeeper commit COMMITMESSAGE`, git uses the **root** user's name and e-mail for the commit message. Setting `git config user.name` on the etc repository doesn't work in this case, because then each time `etckeeper commit` is called, the same data will be used.

What I want is the actual user's name and email be present in the *etckeeper* git repository, so that from the commit log I can track down who did which change.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's strange, as the man page states `Note that etckeeper commit will notice if a user has used sudo or su to become root, and record the original username in the commit.`

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this out and got this for my output on git log:

```
commit 1a8e8fb2952cd6e80f0a5211e8d4e8f698fbd02c
Author: ngrayson <ngrayson@<hostname>
Date:   Thu Jan 10 18:09:47 2013 +0000

    init
```

So it looks like it should grab the user and not run it as root.